# what event should be added for the datagrid so that when the line stops being highlighted, track it?

Tags: c#, datagrid

my code to track the last highlighted line. I want to modify it so that you can delete several elements and so that the last element that was selected is not deleted if the selection is removed from it by clicking on something else, but I don't know how

```cs
        private void customersGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            DataGrid dg = (DataGrid)sender;
            DataRowView rs = dg.SelectedItem as DataRowView;
            if (rs != null)
            {
                Customer.SelectedId = rs["ID"].ToString();
            }
        }
        private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to delete the entry?", "Notification", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Question) == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
            {
                using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
                using (var command = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    command.Connection = connection;
                    command.CommandText = "DELETE FROM Customers WHERE ID='" + Customer.SelectedId + "'";
                    command.ExecuteScalar();
                    GetCustomersFromDataBase();
                }
            }
            
        }
```

I have tried to remove the condition below

```cs
if (rs != null)
```

in order for an empty value to be entered into the variable when nothing is selected, but this did not work

Comment: You should consider using parameters to construct your sql. Then, you could make that a nullable type for that ID and check it first before deletion. If you can't make it nullable, you can set it to an invalid value on empty selection. -1 for example.

Comment: Also: if I remember correctly, you do not need to track selection separately. Just check and get the selection on delete.